# Getting DNS resolution time and response time with Python

Tags: python, curl, dns, performance-testing, pycurl

Does PycURL or any other python pakcage provides information about :

- lookup
- connection time

I would like to get the same information as this cURL command does (without calling the command using subprocess):

Command

```
curl -s -w '\nLookup time:\t%{time_namelookup}\nConnect time:\t%{time_connect}\nPreXfer time:\t%{time_pretransfer}\nStartXfer time:\t%{time_starttransfer}\n\nTotal time:\t%{time_total}\n' -o /dev/null http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Output:

```
Lookup time:    0.029
Connect time:   0.144
PreXfer time:   0.144
StartXfer time: 0.263

Total time: 0.803
```

Comment: Are you just looking for ways to implement this? Do you want to write a tool? Are you after a library that can help implement this?

Comment: I am mainly looking for a library providing these metrics. Or an example of an implementation using PycURL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, PyCurl provides the information. You can derive the information using `pycurl`. It can give a lot of details, not just the ones you mentioned.

Here's a sample code that you can use to derive the same information:

```
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://stackoverflow.com/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
body = buffer.getvalue()

print('TOTAL_TIME: %f' % c.getinfo(c.TOTAL_TIME))
print('CONNECT_TIME: %f' % c.getinfo(c.CONNECT_TIME))
print('PRETRANSFER_TIME: %f' % c.getinfo(c.PRETRANSFER_TIME))
print('STARTTRANSFER_TIME: %f' % c.getinfo(c.STARTTRANSFER_TIME))

c.close()
```

It gives the following results:

```
TOTAL_TIME: 2.252639
CONNECT_TIME: 0.331571
PRETRANSFER_TIME: 0.331634
STARTTRANSFER_TIME: 0.638206
```

I found a [GitHub link](https://github.com/sivsushruth/Cyberboost/blob/master/multithread.py) that mentions some of the other flags as well which can be used in your code.
Here are the flags for a quick view:

```
* EFFECTIVE_URL
* HTTP_CODE
* TOTAL_TIME
* NAMELOOKUP_TIME
* CONNECT_TIME
* PRETRANSFER_TIME
* REDIRECT_TIME
* REDIRECT_COUNT
* SIZE_UPLOAD
* SIZE_DOWNLOAD
* SPEED_UPLOAD
* HEADER_SIZE
* REQUEST_SIZE
* CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD
* CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD
* CONTENT_TYPE
* RESPONSE_CODE
* SPEED_DOWNLOAD
* SSL_VERIFYRESULT
* INFO_FILETIME
* STARTTRANSFER_TIME
* REDIRECT_TIME
* REDIRECT_COUNT
* HTTP_CONNECTCODE
* HTTPAUTH_AVAIL
* PROXYAUTH_AVAIL
* OS_ERRNO
* NUM_CONNECTS
* SSL_ENGINES
* INFO_COOKIELIST
* LASTSOCKET
* FTP_ENTRY_PATH
```

Comment: Great list thanks. I think : HTTP_CODE and RESPONSE_CODE are the same.

Comment: You might want to know what each of these options refer to, if you do [libcurl curl_easy_getinfo](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) is the place to go, with the caveat that in pycurl "the CURLINFO_ prefix has been removed" as per official [PyCurl doc](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/curlobject.html#pycurl.Curl.getinfo)